# Trying to target :nth-child after a certain class using ~

Tags: html, css, sass, css-selectors

I'm using `~` to select list items after the class `.is-middle` is located, the problem is my code doesn't seem to target each list item thereafter so `nth-child(1), nth-child(2)...` doesn't register. Can anyone explain where I may be going wrong with this?

**SCSS**

```
.ctn {



    li {
        width: 100%;
        height: 50px;
        background: lightgrey;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;

        &.is-middle
         ~ li {

             &:nth-child(1) {
               background: purple;
             }

             &:nth-child(2) {
               background: green;
             }

             &:nth-child(3) {
               background: yellow;
             }
        }
    }
    }
```

**PEN:** http://codepen.io/styler/pen/mgfxJ

Comment: if you only want to target the 3 followong siblings, you could use the `+` selector: http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/PBMed/

Comment: hey thanks for the answer! eventually I could be targeting 50+ siblings though so I was hoping to be able to loop through the nth-child index?

Comment: do you know in advance the position (in your example 7th) of the element with the class `.is-middle`? Or will it change dynamicaly?

Comment: Yeah it will change dynamically depending on list length

Comment: what's wrong is that the `:nth-child()` selector is based on the element position inside its parent so you won't find `:nth-child(1)` (the first element) after the middle of the list

Comment: Hey @koala_dev yeah I had a feeling this would be the case, what would you suggest? Maybe loop and add a class to all list items from middle onwards and target these?

Comment: @styler check out my updated answer, the first work around might suit you

Answer (score 2):

**Why you can't use `nth-child` the way you are:**

This selector is based on the position (number)  of the element in it's parent. so targeting `li.is-middle ~ li:nth-child(1)` literaly means the first `li` in its parent  which is after `.is-middle` which doesn't exist.

---

**Work around 1:**

If you don't mind that the first color changes according to the position of `.is-middle`, you may use `:nth-child` like this to color the following siblings:

```
li.is-middle ~ li:nth-child(3n) {
    background: purple;
}
li.is-middle ~ li:nth-child(3n+1) {
    background: green;
}
li.is-middle ~ li:nth-child(3n+2) {
    background: yellow;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/PBMed/3/)**

---

**Work around 2:**

If you only want to target the 3 following siblings, you could use the `+` selector like this:

```
li.is-middle + li {
    background: purple;
}
.ctn li.is-middle + li + li {
    background: green;
}
.ctn li.is-middle + li + li + li {
    background: yellow;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/PBMed/)**